# Simplify JSON Tree

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, html-table

I have a script whose JSON results are as follows:

```
[
  [
    [
      "maturity_date",
      "12/19/2017"
    ],
    [
      "interest_rate",
      0.22
    ],
    [
      "interest_earned",
      264
    ],
    [
      "management_fee",
      5.28
    ],
    [
      "gross_earning",
      1464
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_commission",
      258.72
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_earning",
      1458.72
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "maturity_date",
      "01/30/2018"
    ],
    [
      "interest_rate",
      0.22
    ],
    [
      "interest_earned",
      320.92
    ],
    [
      "management_fee",
      6.42
    ],
    [
      "gross_earning",
      1779.64
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_commission",
      314.5
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_earning",
      1773.22
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "maturity_date",
      "03/13/2018"
    ],
    [
      "interest_rate",
      0.22
    ],
    [
      "interest_earned",
      390.11
    ],
    [
      "management_fee",
      7.8
    ],
    [
      "gross_earning",
      2163.33
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_commission",
      382.31
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_earning",
      2155.53
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to simplify the structure into something as simple as shown below, so that I can display it in a table and also store in a database table in the future. Please note the structure below is most important,just used one data set for illustration

```
[

    {"maturity_date":"12/19/2017","interest_rate":0.22,"interest_earned":264,"management_fee":5.28,"gross_earning":1464,"investor_earning":1458.72},
    {"maturity_date":"01/30/2018","interest_rate":0.22,"interest_earned":264,"management_fee":5.28,"gross_earning":1464,"investor_earning":1458.72},
    {"maturity_date":"03/13/2018","interest_rate":0.22,"interest_earned":264,"management_fee":5.28,"gross_earning":1464,"investor_earning":1458.72},
]
```

There's already code in stack overflow that I can use to create the table if the structure is simplified like above i.e.

```
for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
                                tr = $('<tr/>');
                                tr.append("<td>" + results[i].maturity_date + "</td>" );
                                tr.append("<td>" + results[i].interest_rate + "</td>" );
                                tr.append("<td>" + results[i].interest_earned + "</td>" );
                                tr.append("<td>" + results[i].management_fee + "</td>" );
                                tr.append("<td>" + results[i].gross_earning + "</td>" );
                                tr.append("<td>" + results[i].investor_net_commission + "</td>" );
                                tr.append("<td>" + results[i].investor_net_earning + "</td>" );

                                $('#compound_interest_table tbody').append(tr);

                            }
```

The questions:

1. How can I go about simplifying the initial structure into the structure that I've shown as desirable
2. I feel that the first JSON structure can also be used without simplifying it. If my theory is correct, how then can I use it to modify the Jquery script for the table.

I know this question is a bit similar to the JSON to table questions but having read through them, I can't seem to figure out the last bit so please help.

Comment: #2 could probably work, but I would argue against it as any solution for #2 would either be fragile based on element positions, or would have have logic to find elements.  Changing the initial layout to what you described would be better, imho.

Comment: @Taplar yes, another reason I want to change is to make it easier to search even though the original structure is the same throughout when the script runs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [
  [
    [
      "maturity_date",
      "12/19/2017"
    ],
    [
      "interest_rate",
      0.22
    ],
    [
      "interest_earned",
      264
    ],
    [
      "management_fee",
      5.28
    ],
    [
      "gross_earning",
      1464
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_commission",
      258.72
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_earning",
      1458.72
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "maturity_date",
      "01/30/2018"
    ],
    [
      "interest_rate",
      0.22
    ],
    [
      "interest_earned",
      320.92
    ],
    [
      "management_fee",
      6.42
    ],
    [
      "gross_earning",
      1779.64
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_commission",
      314.5
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_earning",
      1773.22
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "maturity_date",
      "03/13/2018"
    ],
    [
      "interest_rate",
      0.22
    ],
    [
      "interest_earned",
      390.11
    ],
    [
      "management_fee",
      7.8
    ],
    [
      "gross_earning",
      2163.33
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_commission",
      382.31
    ],
    [
      "investor_net_earning",
      2155.53
    ]
  ]
];

var newData = data.reduce(function(collection, element){
  var rowData = {}; //create a new empty row
  
  element.reduce(function(collection, element){
    //put the elements into the row
    rowData[element[0]] = element[1];
    return rowData;
  }, rowData);
  
  collection.push(rowData); //add the row to the results
  return collection;
}, []);

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Map/reduce, where `list` is the structure you provided in your post:

```
list.map(function (propList) {
  return propList.reduce(function (o, prop) {
    o[prop[0]] = prop[1];   
    return o;
  }, {});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For (1), you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
function flatten(array) {
  return array.reduce((obj, v) => {
    obj[v[0]] = v[1];
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

const array = [[], [], [], []];

console.log(array.map(flatten));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Since Taplar put his/her answer first and was correct i gave it the tick. Thanks for the resources linked above :-)